# Json to POJO with springboot creating object with null attributes

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, gson

I'm making a AngularJs + SpringBoot CRUD application. I can retrieve Json on controller correctly, but when i convert to pojo it get null attributes.

Most similiar questions where about misspeled variable names.. I've wrote the class a lot of times e revised it. Still doesnt work.

MODEL:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@SerializedName("id")
private int id;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName("price")
private Long price;

public Car() {

}

public Car(int id, String name, Long price) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}
```

//getters/setters

CONTROLLER:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity add(@RequestBody String jsonCar ) throws Exception {


     Car car = new Gson().fromJson(jsonCar, Car.class);

    // repository.save(car);


     System.out.println("Json== "  + jsonCar);

     System.out.println("pojo==" + car);

     return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);

 }
```

Test output:

Json== {"Car":{"id":3,"name":"car","price":13555}}

pojo==Car {id:0, name:null, price:null}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above JSON object is with String `Car` as key and value of `Car` type JSON Object, where JSON Object has `id`,`name` and `price` properties

```
{
  "id":3,
  "name":"car",
  "price":13555
}
```

So you need outer class that holds `Car` object

```
public class CarResponse {

 @SerializedName("Car")
 private Car car;

 // getters and setters 
}
```

And the convert the string `jsonCar` to `CarResponse`

```
CarResponse car = new Gson().fromJson(jsonCar, CarResponse.class);
 car.getCar() //get the Car object now
```